# Can we cast the type in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Following my query :

> SELECT SQRT((D_o_latitude - T_s_lat)^2+(D_o_longitude - T_s_long)^2)/0.00001 FROM [datasetName.tableName]

I am getting the error as Error: Argument type mismatch in function SUBTRACT:'D_o_latitude' is type string, 'T_s_lat' is type string

So Let me know can we convert the string type to float in the query some thing like casting the data type, I can not change the datatype

Answer (score 80):

With standard SQL you can use [CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) function, eg. `cast(numStringColumn as int64)`. Look out for [standard SQL type names](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types), as they aren't exactly same as legacy SQL.

Answer (score 24):

Under legacy SQL, you can cast types in BigQuery using the following functions: `INTEGER()`, `STRING()`, `BOOLEAN()` `TIMESTAMP()`, and `FLOAT()`.

Use cast() for standard SQL (see opensourcegeek's answer).

In your case, you could write:

```
SELECT SQRT((INTEGER(D_o_latitude) - T_s_lat)^2+(INTEGER(D_o_longitude) - T_s_long)^2)/0.00001 
FROM [datasetName.tableName]
```

Comment: This only works for BigQuery's Legacy SQL, not their latest Standard SQL. Use CAST as discussed below for Standard SQL.

Answer (score 6):

As others have suggested, BigQuery supports [`CAST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast) conversion function which works similar to standard SQL `CAST`.

Example usage:

```sql
SELECT CAST('5.689' AS NUMERIC) as num;
-- num
-- 5.689

SELECT CAST('10E+2' AS NUMERIC) as num;
-- num
-- 1000

SELECT SAFE_CAST('1.123456789123' AS NUMERIC) as num;
-- num
-- 1.123456789
```

---

Though `CAST` is supported in BQ, use of [`SAFE_CAST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#safe_casting) is recommended to avoid query from failing when conversion is not possible.

From docs:

> When using CAST, a query can fail if BigQuery is unable to perform the cast.
>
> If you want to protect your queries from these types of errors, you can use `SAFE_CAST`. `SAFE_CAST` is identical to `CAST`, except it returns `NULL` instead of raising an error.

```sql
SELECT SAFE_CAST('not-a-number' AS NUMERIC) as num;
-- num
-- null
```

**Note**: `SAFE_CAST` is not available in Legacy BigQuery SQL.

---

Together with `IFNULL` (or some other conditional expression), such edge-cases/errors can be handled more gracefully.

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(SAFE_CAST('not-a-number' AS NUMERIC), 0) as num;
-- num
-- 0
```